# Non-Uniform Inter-Row Spacing in tabularx with p Cells

Tags: tables, spacing, paragraphs, tabularx

Take a look at the following picture:

[image]

The Namespace column is typeset using a `p` cell. The page layout is in landscape mode. I've set the inter-row spacing explicitly to `20pt`. However, since the `p` cell in the first row has one extra line of text compared to its neighbors, the row spacing between R1 and R2 is less than that between R2 and R3.

How can I fix this, so that the row spacing takes into account, the height of the `p` cells?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand*{\nkeywfont}{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\nkeyw}[1]{\begingroup \nkeywfont #1\endgroup}
\newcommand{\keyw}[1]{\begingroup \fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont \textbf{#1}\endgroup}

\newcommand{\lbtcell}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{4cm}@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\libtype}[3]{\nkeyw{#1} & \lbtcell{#2} & #3 \\[20pt]}

\begin{document}
{\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rp{4cm}X}
\toprule
Type & Namespace & Description \\
\cmidrule(l{1cm}r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr{1cm}){3-3}

\libtype{size\_type}{\nkeyw{string} \\ \nkeyw{vector<T>} (and all other containers)}{Unsigned type big enough to hold the number of characters in a \nkeyw{string}, or the number of elements in a \nkeyw{vector}. Returned by the \nkeyw{size} function}

\libtype{iterator}{\nkeyw{string}, \nkeyw{vector<T>} (and all other containers)}{Denotes the type of an iterator. Can be used to read and write the element it denotes. May be used only with non\keyw{const} \nkeyw{string}s and containers}

\libtype{const\_iterator}{\nkeyw{string}, \nkeyw{vector<T>} (and all other containers)}{Denotes the type of an iterator. Can be used only to read the element it denotes. If the \nkeyw{string} or container is \keyw{const}, only its \nkeyw{const\_iterator} can be used. However, \nkeyw{const\_iterator} may also be used for non\keyw{const} \nkeyw{string}s and containers}
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\\}  
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual `\\[20pt]` doesn't work, as you discovered. But `booktabs` comes to the rescue:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand*{\nkeywfont}{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\nkeyw}[1]{\begingroup \nkeywfont #1\endgroup}
\newcommand{\keyw}[1]{\begingroup \fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont \textbf{#1}\endgroup}

\newcommand{\lbtcell}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{4cm}@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\newcommand{\libtype}[3]{\nkeyw{#1} & \lbtcell{#2} & #3 \\
  \addlinespace[20pt]
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rp{4cm}X}
\toprule
Type & Namespace & Description \\
\cmidrule(l{1cm}r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr{1cm}){3-3}

\libtype{size\_type}{\nkeyw{string} \\ \nkeyw{vector<T>} (and all other 
containers)}{Unsigned type big enough to hold the number of characters in a \nkeyw{string}, 
or the number of elements in a \nkeyw{vector}. Returned by the \nkeyw{size} function}

\libtype{iterator}{\nkeyw{string}, \nkeyw{vector<T>} (and all other containers)}{Denotes the 
type of an iterator. Can be used to read and write the element it denotes. May be used only 
with non\keyw{const} \nkeyw{string}s and containers}

\libtype{const\_iterator}{\nkeyw{string}, \nkeyw{vector<T>} (and all other 
containers)}{Denotes the type of an iterator. Can be used only to read the element it 
denotes. If the \nkeyw{string} or container is \keyw{const}, only its 
\nkeyw{const\_iterator} can be used. However, \nkeyw{const\_iterator} may also be used for 
non\keyw{const} \nkeyw{string}s and containers}
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Btw, how did you find this out? By experimenting or looking at the code? Because this wasn't explicitly stated in the documentation!

Comment: The doc says it's identical to `\\[<length>]`, and it's almost true. I just tried.

Comment: Missed that part :)